# Compile error / Object initializer with Type ChartArea

Tags: c#, .net, object-initializers

I am using .NET 4.

I experience a strange behaviour with the object initializer combined with the `ChartArea`.

The object initializer works with the `Chart` class:

For example:

```
Chart ch = new Chart { Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom };
```

But it doesn't with the ChartArea:

```
ChartArea ca = new ChartArea { AxisX.Maximum = 1.0 };
```

The IntelliSense displays the `AxisX`, but after implementing it says:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AxisX'

What happens here? Why it doesn't work? Is this a fault by me or by the compiler?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it is because you are trying to set a property of a property? As opposed to `{ AxisX = new Axis { Maximum = 1.0 } }` for example (not sure if that is posible, not familiar with these classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, shoudl work

```
ChartArea ca = new ChartArea { AxisX = new Axis {Maximum = 1.0 }};
```

[Anchor is an enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), whereas [AxisX is an object that represents the primary X-axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`AxisX` must be initialized itself, create a new `Axis` and initialize it.

```
var x = new Axis {Maximum = 1.0 };
ChartArea ca = new ChartArea { AxisX = x };
```